# A question on convergence of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n : (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions that have finite number of maxima and minima, for $n = 1,2,3...$. Let D be a countable dense subset of $(a,b)$. If sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ such that the convergence is non-uniform at the points $x \in D$ and uniform at the points $x \in (a,b)\setminus D$, then does it imply that $f(x) = 0 \forall x \in (a,b)\setminus D$ ?

**EDIT** : The question didn't come out as what i expected. So I am posting a new one. sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: "uniform at the points $x \in (a,b)\setminus D$" seems to be a bit of an unfortunate formulation. Do you mean to say "uniformly on $(a,b) \setminus D$"?

Comment: @Theo : there seems to be a problem

Comment: @Rajesh: Does *non-uniform* mean *pointwise* convergence

Comment: Seems I posted my comment as an answer.  Anyway, @Theo, do you understand "non-uniform" here?  Pointwise but not uniform?

Comment: @Theo, @Glen : I will reformulate with your permission...in few minutes

Comment: @Rajesh and violate my beautiful answer!  How rude :D.

Comment: @Glen : In view of Theo's comments the question doesn'tseems meaningful.

Comment: @chandru1 : yes thats what i intended .

Comment: @Glen : request you to permit me or suggest me if i could post it as another question.

Comment: I basically want discontinuities for $f$ at all $x \in D$.

Comment: @Rajesh I think it's fine to post another question.  Also, if you want the limit to be discontinuous on $D$, then it is perhaps most direct to simply state that as an condition in your new question.

Comment: Please permit me to delete this question. I know its faulty and i don't want to take downvotes. Please let me know how i can delete this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not.  Perhaps you might want to further quantify what you mean by "non-uniform".  Note that the sequence of functions $f_i(x) = c$ where $c$ is a fixed non-zero number converges pointwise (as well as uniformly, of course), and is a counterexample.